# .NET [Authorize] - Use JWT Body Path Other than "Role"

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, authorization, authorize

We have standard .NET Core `[Authorize(Roles = "Foo")]` [authorization attributes](https://%5BAuthorize(Roles%20=%20%22Administrator%22)%5D).

They are set up in `Startup.cs` to check roles via a JWT in the Authorize header in the standard, out-of-the-box way, e.g.:

```
.AddJwtBearer(jwtBearerOptions => {...}
```

Our current tokens look like below and work perfectly:

```
{
  "role": "Foo",
  "exp": 1937249412,
}
```

Our new tokens will look like the tokens below. We have NO control over the incoming tokens (but do have the symmetric key):

```
{
  "www.bar.com/role": "Foo",
  "exp": 1937249412,
}
```

**Core question**: Is there any way to change `[Authorize]` to look for the token in `www.bar.com/role` and not `Role` in the JWT body, which it does by default?

P.S. I know I can add middleware to write a `Role` to the token and re-sign the token. I also know that I can write `[CustomAuthorize]` attributes or use policy-based authentication. It just feels like there should be an easy way to do something this simple without having to mess with incoming requests OR replacing the `[Authorize]` attribute in the whole app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First solution that comes to mind**

You could play it via policies and use roles in the background. Here is an example. In your controller:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Foo")]
public Whatever() {}
```

And then you register your policy like this:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Foo", policy => policy.RequireClaim("www.bar.com/role", new[] { "Foo" }));
}
```

I.e. your "Foo" policy requires a user to have the value "Foo" for the claim "www.bar.com/role".

**Digging deeper into the source**

In fact if you add the `Authorize` attribute with a role, not much more happens in the background as in the Policy example above. .net creates an authorization policy with a `RolesAuthorizationRequirement`, and this requirement checks the roles by calling `context.User.IsInRole`, which, in turn calls `HasClaim(_identities[i].RoleClaimType, role)` on the `ClaimsIdentity`. `RoleClaimType` is set in .net `ClaimsIdentity` to "roles/" by default.

So another way would probably be intercepting the creation of the ClaimsIdentity and calling it with another constructor which has a "roleType" parameter, which allows overriding of the default role claim name.

**A probably better solution**

So I've looked for the ClaimsIdentity and found [this docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0). It seems that you can get to it via token validation parameters:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        RoleClaimType = "www.bar.com/role"
    }
})
```

Comment: I used `IClaimsTransformation` to write a `role` claim if it was missing, but `www.bar.com/role` is present. This is because I needed to check both. Your second solution is ideal if you plan to use a single, non-standard claim. Your link helped me very much, thank you. I used this link: https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-adding-claims-to-existing-identity/, but it's only partially correct. If anyone is doing this in the future, you do NOT need to clone the identity, you can just update the existing one on the Principal.